# How can cordapp version information be retrieved via RPC?

Tags: corda

Is there a way to build a troubleshooting component that reports the Cordapp and Corda version being used by a node in the network?

CordaRPCOps has two methods that retrieve version information but they are only for RPC and Flow version information:

- https://docs.corda.net/clientrpc.html#versioning
- https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.flows/-flow-logic/get-flow-info.html

Answer (score 0):

`CordaRPCOps.protocolVersion` returns the Corda version being run by the node.

As of Corda V3, there is no way to determine the version of each CorDapp the node is running (except for information you can infer from the versions of the flows present on the node). The feature request to add this functionality can be found here: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1212.